# Reading the registry of a windows computer from a web app (silverlight? java?)

Tags: .net, web-applications, registry

Is there a way to read the windows registry from a web based application with no user interaction? I'm open to any technology suggestion.

Comment: Do you want to read a registry entry from the **client** machine? Am I correct (I beg your pardon, it is still early morning there)?

Comment: To clarify the question you should strike PHP, since it won't have any access to a client machine whatsoever.

Comment: @Eineki, im going to have my application running on a web server somewhere, and would like when people load my page i can check a certain key for a certain string in their local registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the short response, as already stated, to your question is NO, you can't access the registry from client.

Maybe you can resort to an activex (bounding your application to Microsoft browsers)

Maybe, if your goal is just to implement some sort of user/license verification (I interpret in this way your response to my comment), you may find useful the webstorage / client side storage alternatives.

As I know there are different implementation, technologies, you can leverage on.

A starting point for your investigations can be

http://wonko.com/post/search-pad-browser-storage

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in java:

```
public class RegistryRead {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   RegistryRead demo = new RegistryRead();
   demo.doit();
   // IO.PressAnyKey();       
   }

 public void doit() {
   displayUserName();
   displayODBCDSN();
   }

 public void displayUserName(){
   com.ms.wfc.app.RegistryKey regKey;
   String userName;
   regKey =
     com.ms.wfc.app.Registry.LOCAL_MACHINE.getSubKey
       ("Network\\Logon");
   if (regKey == null) {
     userName = "Unable to get username from Registry!";
     }
   else {
     userName = (String) regKey.getValue("username");
     }
   System.out.println("Username : " + userName);
   }

 public void displayODBCDSN() {
   com.ms.wfc.app.RegistryKey regKey;
   regKey =
     com.ms.wfc.app.Registry.CURRENT_USER.getSubKey
       ("Software\\ODBC\\ODBC.INI\\ODBC Data Sources");
   if (regKey == null) {
     System.out.println("Unable to get ODBC DSN Registry!");
     }
   else {  
     String dsn [] = regKey.getValueNames();
     System.out.println("ODBC DSN defined : ");
     for(int i = 0;  i < dsn.length; i++) { 
       System.out.println(dsn[i]);
       }
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Web techs such as silverlight are designed to run sandboxed by default. There are certain actions that are allowed/enabled by silverlight that break that convention but they all require *explicit* confirmation by the user.

Comment: how would i access the registry /with/ user confirmation then?

Comment: I said there are _certain actions_, registry access is not one of them. So - the short and firm (eh.. ) answer is still Nope. Can't do that in silverlight.

Answer (score -2):

.NET offers ways of doing this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85t3c3hf.aspx

Comment: i believe your missing the fact that ill be operating in a webbrowser and cant use that

Comment: I second the down vote because the original question was from a Web browser.